# Is it possible to construct any random vector in any dimension with iid components so its norm is a given positive (or nonnegative) random vector?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $N$ be a random variable, assumed to be nonnegative or positive, as required. Let $m$ be a given dimension, $m\ge 1.$ Then we can see that we can always construct $X_m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}(\pm N, \pm N, \dots \pm N)$ so that $||X_m||=N.$ But in this case, the components aren't iid, they're just identical but not independent.

My question is: is it possible to always construct $X_m:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}(N_1\dots N_m), N_i \sim_{iid}N,$ so that $||X_m||=N?$ Any hint is appreciated! If the general answer is no, then is there a condition we could put on $N$ to make this happen? Thank you!

Comment: If we can adjust the constant $m$ then it should be possible

Comment: @VezenBU Sorry, but what did you mean by adjusting $m,$ which is given and fixed?

Comment: I mean adjust the constant on RHS, instead of using $1/\sqrt{m}$, can we use something else?

Comment: I don't understand. You say that $N$ is a random vector, but then you say $\|X_m\| = N$, so that implies that $N$ is a (non-negative) real number. Can you clarify ?

Comment: @StratosFair Sorry , my mistake $N$ is a nonnegative or positive (as required) random variable, not a random vector!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to rephrase your question slightly to make it more precise:

> Let $N$ be a non-negative random variable and $m \geq 1$.
> Does there necessarily exist a an $m$-dimensional random vector $X$ with iid entries $X_i$ such that $\lVert X \rVert_2 \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=} N$?

Notice that this is equivalent to finding a distribution of the $X_i$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m X_i^2
\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=} 
N^2. \tag{1}
$$

This is not true in general.
For example, if we take $N \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, it's not too hard to see that for $m > 1$, there is no possible distribution for the $X_i$.

The condition that you are looking for is called ["infinite divisibility"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)), which would ensure that $N^2$ can be written as the sum of $m$ iid random variables for any $m > 1$.
The $X_i$ would then be the square roots of these random variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll look into the condition of infinite divisibility, was totally unknown to me! Just to double check I understood correctly: the reason Bernoulli distribution serves as a counter example to infinite divisibility for dimension $m=2$ is that there exists no independent pair $X_1, X_2$ so that $X_1^2 + X_2^2 = 0^2=0$ ith probability $1/2,$ is this correct?

Comment: Correct! And the reason that you can't find such $X_i$ is that for $X_1^2 + X_2^2$ to have support $\{0, 1\}$ each $X_i^2$ must have $0$ and $1/2$ in their supports. But then $X_1^2 + X_2^2$ would have $1/2$ in its support.

Comment: @LearningMath Infinite divisibility comes in of you want that result to be true for every $m$. With  $m$  fixed this does not involve Infinite divisibility .